# What does the "=!" operator do?

Tags: c++, c, operators

I accidentally typed `=!` instead of `!=` that caused a huge bug in a system that went undetected for a while; I have fixed it since but I'm curious as to what `=!` does.

I had something like this

```
void foo(int param)
{
    int a = 0;

    ... 

    if (a =! param)
    {
        // never got here even when `a` was not equal to `param`  
    }
    ...
}
```

Can someone explain what the above `if` statement is evaluating ?

Comment: Hasn't this been asked (and no, I'm not thinking of `while (x --> 0)`)?

Comment: @chris I have not had any luck searching for queries with operators.

Comment: @ProfessorChaos, I understand that. It's hard to find questions that you know will rely on symbols that search engines discard.

Comment: @Mehrdad Not everything is obvious to everyone and not everything is easy to search. I see it's super trivial now. If you think you should penalize me for not being able to think like you and as fast as you then so be it.

Comment: @ProfessorChaos Downvotes are not punitive. Don't worry about them.

Comment: @ProfessorChaos: Sorry, I think there's a misunderstanding. I didn't downvote because I thought it was obvious (totally agree with your statement), I downvoted because a five-second search for `C operators` would have shown you that no such operator exists, making you think maybe something else is going on. Or if it wouldn't have made you think of an other possibility, I would have at least hoped to read that you looked but didn't know how an operator that doesn't exist could still compile. Anyway, don't take it personally... I downvoted the question, not you! Research effort was all.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This expression:

```
a =! param
```

assigns the value `!param` to `a`. `!param` is negated version of param evaluated in boolean context.

Assignment operators return the value of the right hand side, so, `if (a = !param)` also executes the `if` body, if `!param` is true.

Answer (score 12):

It's not a single `=!` operator. It's `=` and `!`, assignment and negation.

It's equivalent to `if (a = !param)`, or

```
a = !param;

if (a) {

}
```

Answer (score 7):

`=!` is not an operator. It is the `=` (assignment) operator, and the `!` (boolean not) operator.

So you have `if (a = !param)`. The assignment returns the value of the assignment, so you essentially have:

```
a = !param;
if (a) {
   ...
```

Answer (score 5):

If you consider that it can be multiple tokens the effect should be simple:

```
if (a = !param)
```

Answer (score 2):

Important:       `'=!' != '!='` :)

But:    `'=!'  ==  'assignment of the negation of a value'`

e.g. in pseudo:

```
bool a= true;
bool b=!a;
```

so b is false!

Answer (score 1):

=! Is not an operator. You can understand it like this. Suppose there is a statement `a=!b` it is an assignment of operand b in a but here the twist is before assigning b to a we are reversing the state of b by prefixing operand b with ! which is basically logical not operator.