# What's this =! operator?

Tags: c++, c, operators

I was surprised by this code:

```
if (a =! b) { // let it be on false
    ...
}
```

But `a` is never assigned by a value. What's this operator about?

Comment: `"But a is never assigned by a value"` - what are you trying to say by this?

Comment: Pre-ANSI C apparently had a few things like that (`=+` instead of `+=`).  But I doubt this code is that old.  Assuming the comment's correct, the code needs to be fixed.

Comment: @MaxLybbert B seem to have had `=|`, `=&`, `=+`, `=-`, `=%`, `=*`, and `=/` (see http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/kbman.html), but probably not `=!`

Comment: [lol, here's the Java version of the same question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825840/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-java)

Comment: It's *almost* Yoda's `!=` operator. "a equals not b". Better would be "a, b, equals not". But `a b =!` or `a,b =!` doesn't compile.

Comment: you can omit spaces in a lot of C. you can write a program like this: `#include <stdio.h>` `int main(){int a=0;int b=1;if(a=!b){printf("hello");}else{printf("bye");}};` hope my C isn't so rusty that I made a syntax error... anyway here are some examples of how evil you can be: the [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/).

Comment: This bears remarkable similarity to the "goes to" operator `-->` as used in `while(i --> 10)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator

Comment: Note that Visual C++ will emit *warning C4706: assignment within conditional expression* for this. Not sure about GCC.

Comment: I think more likely a typo of someone trying to type `if (a == !b)`

Comment: You marked this question with the C++ tag.. So, it can really be anything, depending on the type of a, because of operator overloading. In this case, the overloaded operator is the `=`. Unless you're using a variation of C or C++ with has a special meaning for that

Comment: Put `if (a =! b)` into Visual Studio and press `Ctrl+k,d` and you will see it miraculously turn into `if (a = !b)`

Comment: @llquixotic `a,b =! -- yoda;` compiles if `b` is an integral type and `yoda` is an `int`.

Comment: When you say *`"But a is never assigned by a value."`*, do you mean that 1) prior to the **`if (a =! b) {`** statement, a was undefined, or 2) after the **`if ... {`** statement, a was unchanged?

Comment: If you like that one, you might be interested in the NAND operator, which is written `&~` as in `a = b &~ c`.

Comment: @ThomasW. Doesn't always work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228060/what-does-the-operator-do?lq=1

Answer (score 391, accepted):

That's two operators, `=` and `!`, not one. It might be an obfuscated way of writing

```
a = !b;
if (a) {
    // whatever
}
```

setting `a` to the logical inverse of `b`, and testing whether the result is true (or, equivalently, whether `b` was false).

Or it might be a mistyping of `a != b`.

Comment: I wonder if it was a typo of someone trying to type != especially since it is in an if statement

Comment: @Cyber: Good point, worth mentioning in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sadly it may be the case that somebody just considers this "their style".

Comment: Whoever writes obsfuscated code by making up their own operators can `-->` hell. Wait, nooooooooooo!

Comment: @Cyber almost certainly not a mistyping, as the comment that follows it makes a vague kind of logical sense given what it actually does.  I wouldn't be able to interpret that comment without the code, but it definitely seems to be in agreement.

Comment: For major obfuscation points, if the = operator was overriden to return something OTHER than the LHS, you could have some REAL fun.

Comment: @corsiKa You're safe! Someone beat you to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator?lq=1

Comment: @corsiKa Damn, this probably means that there’s a special place in hell [reserved just for me](https://github.com/klmr/named-operator) …

Comment: @Jules I would still say it's a mistype. Surely the original author didn't mean to type `a =! b` instead of `a = !b`.

Comment: @Caltor I think you overestimate the ability of developers to do incredibly stupid things on purpose.

Comment: Can anyone provide an example of what reason this code might be used, or the concept of assigning `NOT var` to something? I haven't experienced it myself and can't create an example.

Comment: @Cyber The OP said *"a is never assigned by a value"* implying this couldn't be a mistype of `!=` because `a` is not assigned anywhere else. (Since the OP originally did not know this *was* an assignment.) Though what the OP meant by *"assigned by a value"* is grammatically vague.

Comment: @HC_ It's all going to be obscure-seeming. Maybe `b` is actually a method call or non-boolean.

Comment: We had a programmer that liked to write =! instead of !=. He's no longer with us, so I can't ask him why.

Perhaps there's a lesson there somewhere...

Answer (score 280):

Long ago, when dinosaurs roamed the earth and C ran on 5th edition UNIX on PDP-11s, `=!` was the 'not equals' operator.  This usage was deprecated by the creation of *Standard C*, so now it means 'assign the logical inverse', as in `a = !b`.  This is a good argument for always surrounding binary operators with spaces, just to make it clear to the *humans* reading the code what the compiler is thinking.

I'm a bit surprised nobody else mentioned this, but then again I may be the only SO user to have ever touched a C compiler that old.

Comment: **+1**: I ruled out any sort of ancient syntax the second I saw the `//` single-line comment. This code ***has*** to be C++ or some newer version of C for it not to have a `/* ... */` comment. Nice bit of trivia nonetheless.

Comment: s/dinosaurs/[compusaurs](http://alumnus.caltech.edu/~lschmidt/compusaurus.html) :)

Comment: This is actually the only good answer to 'What's this operator about?'. All the others seem to try to ignore the existence of the operator.

Comment: So, were dinosaurs as cool as we imagine?

Comment: Its also a good argument for designing languages to not use assignment as a boolean operator with a return value.

Comment: In elder days before the fall of mighty kings in Gondolin the ancient scribes would also invert the order of assignment operators, writing `a =+ b` to mean what we now render as `a += b`.  Digraphic operators have a nasty way of mixing up with monographic ones when whitespace doesn’t matter but order does: consider `a =- b`,`a = -b`, vs `a -= b`. Here of old be dragons, but none so great as before after Eärendil slew Ancalagon the Black and broke Thangoradrim beneath his fall. I was there when we thought evil vanquished forever, but ever it returns from the darkest of codes to trouble us anew.

Comment: @tchrist: s/Thangoradrim/Thangorodrim/

Answer (score 54):

`a` is assigned the boolean negation of `b` in that line. It is just a misformatted

```
if( a = !b ) {
```

... and an evil hidden assignment inside a condition.

Comment: Assignments inside a condition are not evil... though in this case the use of whitespace is confusing.

Comment: Assignments in a condition are indeed evil.  It's important when you're coding to produce something that can be read and understood with a minimum of effort.  Readability is an important part of maintainability.  So if you're writing a condition - make it look like a condition.  If you're doing an assignment - make it look like an assignment.  Never try to disguise one as the other, or bury one within the other.

Comment: `while (--t) { ... }` is common, but it's not exactly the assignment operator.

Comment: @Vortico but it is not so easily readable, and may cause headache if someone writes `--t+y`, for example

Answer (score 46):

```
a =! b
```

is just a funny way of putting

```
a = !b
```

i.e. the assignment of `not b` to `a`.

The value of the expression is `a` after the assignment.

With the code below you can see that the value of the expression `a = !b` is `!false` (i.e. `true`), and you can then see the assignment has taken place by checking the value of `a`, which is also `true`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{ 
    bool a = false;
    bool b = false;

    if(a)
        printf("a is true!\n");
    else
        printf("a is false!\n");

    if(a = !b)
        printf("expression is true!\n");
    else
        printf("expression is false!\n");

    if(a)
        printf("a is true!\n");
    else
        printf("a is false!\n");

}
```

Result:

```
a is false!
expression is true!
a is true!
```

Comment: If by "a funny way" you mean evil and confusing, sure :)

Comment: That is exactly what I mean!

Answer (score 35):

**[Operators in C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++)**

According to C/C++ operators list there is no operator such as `=!`. However, there is an operator `!=` (**Not equal to**, *Comparison operators/relational operator*)

#### There are two possibilities.

1. It *could* be typo mistake as I've noticed that `=!` operators is in `if` statement and someone is trying to type `!=` instead of `=!` because `!=` is the comparison operator which returns *true or false*.
2. Possibly, the developer was trying to assign the boolean negation of `b` to `a` and he/she has done a typo mistake and forgot to put a space after equal sign.  This is how the compiler interprets it, anyways.
   According to **[Operator precedence in c++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++)**:

   - Operator **Logical NOT (`!`) precedence** is **3** and **Associativity** is **Right-to-left**
   - Operator **Direct assignment (=) precedence** is **16** and **Associativity** is **Right-to-left**

Comment: thanks for the link to the operator precedences, that's really important to keep in mind in general.

Comment: Please explain why operator precedence and associativity are important for parsing `a =! b`...

Comment: =! is not single operator, they are two. So compiler use precedences and associativity to execute these two operator. Which one has to execute first and second. May this help u

Answer (score 21):

They are two different operators: the `=` (assignment) operator together with the `!` operator. It can basically be translated to an assignment of `a` to the negated value of `b`.

```
if (a = !b)
```

But, what the user, probably, meant to write was the `!=` operator:

```
if (a != b)
```

Answer (score 20):

That is not a single operator, it is however, a great way to obfuscate code.

If it were written `a=!b` instead, the white space might not lead you to believe that it was a single operator.

Compilers have warnings for assignment in a conditional expression unless you wrap the entire statement in a set of parenthesis, and this is a perfect example of when this warning would be useful.

Both of these statements are functionally identical, but one generates a warning and the other does not:

```
if (a =! b)   // Generates a warning with `-Wparentheses` (gcc)

if ((a =! b)) // No such warning
```

> **-Wparentheses**
>
> > Warn if parentheses are omitted in certain contexts, such as when there is an assignment in a context where a truth value is expected, or when operators are nested whose precedence people often get confused about.

This, of course, assumes that you are a responsible programmer and actually read the warnings your compiler spits out.

---

#### Using white space in a more reasonable way, the statement is actually:

```
if (a = !b) // Assign A the value of (logical) NOT B and then test the truth
```

The compiler warning mentioned above is actually useful in the case where the person who wrote this code accidentally transposed `!` and `=`. However, from the cryptic inline comments in your original question, `a = !b` is probably the author's intention.

Answer (score 18):

C++ does not have an `=!` operator, which immediately means that this is an `=` operator followed by a `!` operator. So, you simply have `a = !b` in the `if` condition.

Answer (score 12):

This is all about clarity of code:

It should be written as: `if (a = !b)`

`if (a = !b)` is the same as saying if  `a` is assigned to `!b`. So there are technically 2 separate operators being used, `=` which is an assignment operation, and `!` which is a logical expression.

Just put a **space** between `=` and `!` it solves this confusion.

Answer (score 11):

**There could be three reasons for this:**

1. It could be a mistyping of the `!=` operator, meaning not equal to. *Example:*

   ```
   if (a != b) {
       // a is not equal to b
   }
   ```
2. It could be a mistyping `a == !b`, meaning `a` is equal to not `b`, which would most commonly be used with booleans. *Example:*

   ```
   if (a == !b) {
       // The boolean a is equal to not b (a is not equal to b)
   }
   ```
3. It could be trying to assign `a` to the inverse of `b`. *Example:*

   ```
   bool a = !b; // Sets a to the opposite of b
   ```

Comment: 2) Not weird, downright wrong; 3) Why not in an if statement? Did someone remove the return value from assignments while no one was looking?

Answer (score 10):

I think this is one of the writing or printing mistake. Because if we can not compile this code as it holds a compiletime error. And here this is inside **if** clause, the return type must be boolean. So how can it possible. The answer is simply a  mistake or as Mike said *obfuscated way of writing*.

And only possible if both variables a and b are boolean which will be compiled as **a is equal to (not)b**  i.e (a = !b) .

Answer (score 6):

This can be taken as `a` is assigned to `!b`.

Answer (score 4):

I am trying to answer your question and, in agreement with Mike's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21029199/2188875), I am just adding up.

You can also understand it by `a=!!b`.
The code `a=!b` returns `0` to `a` and `a=!!b` returns `1` to `a`.

The `=!` is not a single operator but the mix of these two.
These types of question are asked to misguide students to *check their coding skills*.

Comment: To link to an answer just click on the **Share** button at the end of the post, copy the link and enter it like this: `[answer](http://link)`.